# How to get gender and age graph in Twitter?

Tags: twitter, graph, twitter-oauth

I have to show graph for gender and age in twitter like facebook demograph (attached with this)...

Is it possible to get data for gender and age from twitter using oauth or api according to follower count ?

[image]

Thanks in advance....

Comment: No. Twitter does not release that information through their API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Twitter Employee @episod Taylor Singletary,

> Demographic data such as this is not available from the API -- and not
>   always appropriate as Twitter accounts can represent many things not
>   limited to persons alive or dead.

Read his answer [here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/5030)

Answer (score 1):

When you create a twitter account, it never asks for gender. So there is no question to get it through the API.